# Rails: Scope an entire model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, scope

I am imagining something similar to this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    default_scope -> { where(public: true) }

end
```

Now whenever the User model gets accessed it should always append `where(public: true)` to querys. So `all` would end up being `all.where(public: true)`.

I'm trying to put something like this into the `ApplicationRecord` class to override behavior on all inheriting models, thus manually overriding is not an option for me.

Comment: Does that `default_scope` will be same for all inheriting models?

Comment: @Pavan yes. That's why I want to inherit :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `default_scope` remains same for all inheriting models, then you can consider putting that in a custom model and let all other models inheriting from that model

```
class CustomModel < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope -> { where(public: true) }
end
```

And let other models inherit from that custom model like so

```
class A < CustomModel
end
```

Comment: I did not know about the presence of `default_scope`, but seems my gut instinct was right :)

Answer (score 0):

If all your models have `public` as a property, then you can add the `default_scope` on all the models by adding it to `app/models/application_record.rb`;

However, having a `default_scope` of `where(public: true)` is a little bit tricky here cause you won't be able to access the data `not_public` data unless you use the `unscoped` method: `User.unscoped`.

That being said, it's better if you add a scope `scope :public, -> () { where(public: true) }` and call it whenever you want to make sure that your user is public:

`User.public.find_by(email: 'xxxxx')`

Comment: I know the benefits and 'risks' of using default_scope and I am not using it for the example I illustrated it in the post. I am using it for a gem -> https://github.com/slooob/sandboxy However I wound up doing something similar to adding it to application_record by binding it to the `sandboxy` method provided by the gem. The gem requires that no additional scopes are necessary to make it work like intended.